# Create copy of class passed as argument

Tags: vba, excel, class

I am creating a project in VBA to automate handling of asynchronous quasi-multithreading (mouthful, sorry). This revolves around creating and running multiple copies of a class which `Implements` a certain interface, and raises some known events when the async task is complete. The interfacing is similar to [this example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/163158/using-events-together-with-interfaces-in-vba)

My program calls the class to execute its code, and listens to the events raised, that's all working fine. Now my final task is to take any given class which `Implements` the appropriate interface, and make multiple copies to set running in parallel.

How do I make copies of a class which is passed to a routine?

How can I take a class reference and make several `New` versions?

Or in code, each one of my thread classes (the classes which handle the async class which is passed) will have a `Worker` property to save their task.

```
Private workerObject As IWorker
Public Property Set Worker(workObj As IWorker) 'pass unknown class with IWorker interface
    'What goes here?
    Set workerObject = workObj
    'This won't work as then every thread points to the same worker
    'I want something to create a New one, like
    Set workerObject = New ClassOf(workObj)
    'But of course that doesn't work
End Property
```

Comment: If you want to clone an instance you would need to do so manually, i.e. add a .Clone() method that creates a new instance then assigns its own internal state to it & then returns it.

Comment: @AlexK. that's not ideal as I'll have to make sure my `IWorker` interface stipulates a `.Clone()` function, which seems arbitrary and misplaced in the sorts of classes I'll be passing. I don't necessarily want a clone either, I'd like a new instance if I could.

Comment: You can have a Function (f.eks. `Create`) as part of the implementing class (set its `Predeclared ID` to true) and have it create a new clean instance. Then you can declare `Dim W as IWorker`, `Set W = New IWorker`, `Set W = Worker.Create`(where `Worker` is the implementing class). Take a look [here](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2016/07/05/oop-vba-pt-2-factories-and-cheap-hotels/) for a better explanation.

Comment: I wonder if I could pass `byVal`, it doesn't seem to be working but that may be an implementation error - anyone know if this should work in theory? Or why it shouldn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to inspect the possible types and act accordingly:

```
Dim workerObject As IWorker

If TypeOf workObj Is ImplementingClass1 Then
    Set workerObject = New ImplementingClass1

ElseIf TypeOf workObj Is ImplementingClass2 Then
    Set workerObject = New ImplementingClass2

End If
```

Alternatively you could add a factory method to the interface:

```
Public Function CreateNew() As IWorker: End Function
```

Implement it in the classes:

```
Public Function IWorker_CreateNew() As IWorker
    Set IWorker_CreateNew = New ImplementingClass1
End Function
```

And then:

```
Set workerObject = workObj.IWorker_CreateNew()
```